# How to change the size of shared system memory?

Tags: windows-10, memory, bios

I have a situation here. Today, I checked the graphics properties of my PC and I found this:

Total available graphics memory : 956 MB

Dedicated video memory: 0 MB

System video memory: 0 MB

Shared system memory: 956 MB

All of my available graphics memory is being used as shared system memory and there's nothing left for dedicated video memory. I searched on the internet about this problem and found a few solutions:

1. Changing the size of video memory through BIOS
2. Changing it's size through registry
3. Changing the size of shared system memory through BIOS

None of the above seem to be working. I entered BIOS and found that video memory was already set to 128 MB. I tried changing it to 64 and 256 but windows still showed it 0 in graphics properties. There is no option in BIOS to change shared system memory. So I need your help to fix this!

BTW, I'm using Windows 10, to which I recently upgraded from Windows 7.
My PC specs:
CPU: Intel Pentium 1
RAM: 2 GB
Graphics: Intel Express Graphics

Edit:
When I was previously using Windows 10, this issue was not there. Then I switched to Windows 7 for a few months. Windows 7 didn't have this issue as well. Recently, I switched back to Windows 10 and now I'm stuck with this problem. I really don't want to reinstall Windows again. Is there anything in the registry that I could change to fix this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: "All of my available graphics memory is being used as shared system memory and there's nothing left for dedicated video memory." - Your system does not have any dedicated video memory.  Intel Express Graphics can only use shared memory and more than likely is limited to 1 GB.  This is due to the fact your entire system only has 2 GB.

Comment: I accept that. But my actual problem is with video memory showing 0 MB . And i don't know what to do.

Comment: I assume you have the current Intel drives installed on your system, they won't actually be all that recent, due to the age of your hardware.

Comment: Yes. All the drivers are up to date as per my hardware capacity. You might want to read the comment below the first answer in this post to get some additional info about my problem.

Comment: I shouldn't have to read a comment to an answer to gain relevant information that should be in your question.

Comment: I apologize for that

Comment: If you can get a USB drive of 2-4 Gb you can install Linux on it and test if it works good enough in your system. SteamOS won't work, but Ubuntu Gamepack or SparkyLinux could work. there is a Fedora games distro too.

Answer (score 0):

> CPU: Intel Pentium 1    ....   RAM: 2 GB

That is not nearly enough memory overall. The CPU is weak as well, even for Windows 7.

Add memory (8 GB minimum) and then see if the problem disappears. You need more RAM if you expect to use it also for shared memory. What you have is not enough for that.

You may need to upgrade the computer.

Comment: Well, previously, I was using Windows 10. Then I switched to Windows 7 for a while and then again switched back to Windows 10. When I was previously on Windows 10 and 7, it showed video memory correctly in graphics properties. But now it isn't. That's the problem and I don't actually want to reinstall Windows on my PC. I am fully assured that there is no problem with the hardware.

Comment: 2 GB is not really enough for Windows 7 either. 4 GB min. for Windows 7. And again, that may help with the video memory.

Comment: You won't believe it but I was running Windows 7 32 bit butter smooth on 1 GB RAM . It consume 400-500 MB of RAM. Currently on Windows 10 32 bit, it consumes about 800-900 MBs which is fine. Everything runs smooth except for games because there is problem with video memory and that's why I've posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

### See [Windows 10 min system requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-system-requirements-6d4e9a79-66bf-7950-467c-795cf0386715)

```
Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster processor or SoC

RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 2 GB for 64-bit

Hard disk space: 16 GB for 32-bit OS or 20 GB for 64-bit OS

Graphics card: DirectX 9 or later with WDDM 1.0 driver

Display: 800 x 600
```

Your CPU is probably underpowered and you are low on RAM. Stick with Win 7 if it worked earlier.

However, I suspect that the culprit is the DirectX 9 requirement. I don't think your built-in Intel graphics are DirectX9 compatible. Download the DirectX 9 drivers and see if they work.